# LINUX - how can I detect CPU architecture through terminal?

Tags: linux, ssh, 64-bit, architecture, 32-bit

I have a machine on my network that I can only access through ssh, and I want to see if it'll support a 64-bit OS (currently running linux, but I don't know which). Any ideas how to accomplish this through terminal command/s? thanks.

Comment: How many duplicates of this question do we need, really?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cat /proc/cpuinfo

look for the 'lm' flag, it means 'long-mode' i.e. 64-bit capable.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to see the "bitnes" of the OS installed you can run this command.

```
$ uname -m
```

Regarding the actual capabilities of the processor you can always look the model up inside /proc.

> $ cat /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 1):

egrep '(vmx|svm)' --color=always /proc/cpuinfo